# Android JSONAException value of type java.lang.String cannot be contvert to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json

at the php json_encode, i will return this

```
[{"item":"item1"},{"item":"item2"},{"item":"item3"}]
```

At the eclipse, i use this to retrieve the array

```
String content = Converter.convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);


item = new String[jsonArray.length()];

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
SONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
item[i] = jsonObject.getString("item");
}
```

However, i receive this

```
org.json.JSONException: Value item1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JASONArray
```

How do i have to do to fix this

Comment: Which line throws the exception? What is the definition of `content`?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content); this line throw the exception

Comment: If the exception is raised in this line I'm pretty sure your server is not returning what you are expecting. Try to print the content-String to a log to find out what you are actually getting back from your server.

Comment: I tried your code with a hard-coded string: `String content = "[{\"item\":\"item1\"},{\"item\":\"item2\"},{\"item\":\"item3\"}]";` and it works fine. I think @MichaelSchmidt is correct - the error is related to not receiving the data you expect.

Comment: I found my problem already, is in my php file while i wanted to test the output of array, and i forgot to remove the echo after testing

Comment: Question no longer valid because, from comments: "I found my problem already, is in my php file while i wanted to test the output of array, and i forgot to remove the echo after testing" –  Tiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem already, is in my php file while i wanted to test the output of array, and i forgot to remove the echo after testing